# circular profile pic swift

Tags: ios, swift

I feel like im overlooking something:
my image still shows up like a diamond shape. Im trying to get it to be circular.

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var  profileImageView: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true;

       }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }
```

}

Comment: Are you using Storyboards? Are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the profileImageView is changing its size after the viewDidLoad and ending up smaller than it was when you set the corner radius.  You can test this theory by moving your corner radius code to viewDidAppear.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` would be better. It is called after Auto Layout but before the view is on screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might need to change `clipsToBounds = true` to `layer.masksToBounds = true`, as the masking needs to happen on the layer, not on the image view itself. I have that same effect in my app, here's the code:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2.0
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Hope that helps.